# Table doesn't exist in engine - xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I updated my xampp from 7.0.13 to 7.1.1 a few days ago. 
Today I wanted to continue programming on my localhost. But phpMyAdmin is throwing the error 'Table xxx doesn't exist in engine'. Where I can actually see all my tables in the navbar. 
I read some things online, but I couldn't find a working solution for me. As I'm working on a MacBook, not every folder seems to have the same name as on windows or linux machines. 

Could someone of you help me out here? Because it would be a huge amount of work to redo all of the work. 
Is there a possibility to copy some files or something from my mac so I could take these and use these on another machine?